# Incoming Outgoing Packets Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

Is there a way to have a column or a filter that marks each packet as **incoming** (*download*) or **outgoing** (*upload*) in **Wireshark**?

I guess this should be relative to the selected capture interface device.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Color Rule (under `View -> Colorize Conversation -> New Coloring Rule` and ad `ip.src == your.ip` as a color and `ip.dst == your.ip` as another color. This would override the defaults but would accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: I was thinking more like a special column with a value download = "1" and upload = "2". I don't see anything like tokens in Wireshark where i can append a string to an expression.
I want another program to take this data and know when a packet is an upload and a download. With this answer this other program will have to check the ip.src == my.ip & ip.dst == my.ip instead of a 1 or a 2.